# AMPscript acronym

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've always wondered, what are the three 'AMP' words in the AMPscript acronym?

I guessed it could be **A**dam's **M**arvellous **P**rogramming — but while [Adam](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) may be very knowledgeable in AMPscript, the language is probably not attributed to him...

Comment: Most language names have no particular meaning, but I'm sure Adam appreciates the compliment.

Comment: I look forward to Adam's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to someone that I thought might know.  He said:

> I actually remember asking during developer orientation and no one knew. I do know for certain though that it is not an acronym.

Comment: My guess is it was conjured from of the ExactTarget marketing dept then — probably after a few glasses of red wine...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: **A**utomated **M**arketing **P**rogramming **script** language.